# nsdialog example throws exception

Tags: nsis, nsdialogs

I have been using NSIS (2.33) for and while, but am a newbie with nsDialogs, so am working through the examples at:

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/nsDialogs/Readme.html

However, once I get to the "Creating Page" example, which adds the lines:

```
    nsDialogs::Create 1018
    Pop $Dialog
```

I then get an exception when I run it.

Trying later examples on the page, these will not even compile, as I get:

```
    Invalid command: ${NSD_Check}
```

I am cut-and-pasting the examples, so can't see what I'm doing wrong!

Can anyone offer a newbie some advice?

Comment: do you include the `nsdialogs.nsh` file in your script?

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to NSIS v2.46 to get the latest version of nsdialogs.nsh along with the bugfixes for plugin itself.